# function passing by reference

Tags: javascript, function

after I run below codes why myArray is still [2, 3, 4, 5], why it is not changed to []?

```
var myArray = [2, 3, 4, 5];
function doStuff(arr) {
  arr = [];
}

doStuff(myArray);
```

However when I do below steps , myArray did change to [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

```
var myArray = [2, 3, 4, 5];
function doStuff(arr) {
  arr.push(6);
}

doStuff(myArray);
```

I am very confusing about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr` is a local variable in

```
function doStuff(arr) {
  arr = [];
}
```

The line `arr = [];` assigns a brand new object to `arr`, so that it no longer points to the passed array. Since the local variable `arr` goes out of scope when the function returns, this assignment has no effect. It certainly doesn't effect the non-local variable `myArray` in the caller's scope.

On the other hand, the second function:

```
function doStuff(arr) {
  arr.push(6);
}
```

actually does something with the passed array, calling the `push` method on the object that `arr` names. Note that `arr` isn't redefined in the body of the function, so that it never loses its identity as a name for the passed array.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is okey if you don't have references to the *myArray* because this actually creates an empty array. If you have references to *myArray* from another variable in somewhere of your code, you coudn't set as null you did. As an alternative, you can use following method to clear. Otherwise, if it is not important, you can remove references.

```html
while(myArray.length > 0) {
    myArray.pop();
}
```